# Using statement or GC to dispose of a connection

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns

I'm using a pattern where I constructor inject an IDbConnection instance into my class which is then assigned to a local variable before being used with Dapper to populate a List with objects from a database.

I understand that best practice is to wrap the connection object in a using statement, however when I try and reuse the connection to reload objects, I cannot because the connection has already been disposed. Would it be ok for me to just open and close the connection in the LoadValues method, and trust the class destructor to dispose of my object instead of having a using statement? Perhaps there's a better way that I've not considered?

Here is my class:

```
Public Class AmountLookup : Implements INAmountLookup
    Private _listOfRecords As New List(Of NAmount)
    Private ReadOnly _mfConnection As IDbConnection
    Private ReadOnly _fRepository As IFRepository

    Sub New(mfConnection As IDbConnection,
            fRepository As IFRepository)
        _mfConnection = mfConnection
        _fRepository = fRepository
        LoadValues()
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadValues() Implements INAmountLookup.LoadValues
        LoadValues(DateGateway.GetLastWorkingDayOfPreviousMonth)
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadValues(currentNDate As Date) Implements INAmountLookup.LoadValues
        _listOfRecords.Clear()

        Dim sql = String.Format(SqlFactory.GetSql(DBC.SQLs.ValidatedNAmounts),
                                _fRepository.GetFormattedListOfFsForSqlSearch,
                                Format(currentNDate, DBC.DateFormats.MfDate))

        Using _mfConnection
            _mfConnection.Open()
            _listOfRecords = _mfConnection.Query(Of NAmount)(sql).ToList
            _mfConnection.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Function Find(fCodeValue As String) As NAmount Implements INAmountLookup.Find
        Dim myList = _listOfRecords.Where(Function(x) x.FCode = fCodeValue)
        Return myList.SingleOrDefault()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Are you talking about mfConnection ?  What makes you think the class destructor would dispose that object.  That was passed to the class - not created in the class.

Comment: Also you should use parameters for your sql and not just raw strings into which you have placed test values, as this is open to SQL injection attack

Comment: Good point Blam, I didn't realise that though it makes sense now you state it. And Sam I see your point, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are being passed the connection then you should not dispose of it unless you are also taking over responsibility for the lifetime of the connection, ie the thing passing you the connection knows that they are transferring ownership of the connection to your class, and so won't try and give it to anyone else or try and use if after your class has become the owner.

It sounds like this is not that case (as something else is also trying to use it) so you should do one of two things:

- Assume that the object which gave you the connection is remaining the owner as so leave it to them to dispose of it (and probably open and close it)
- Transfer ownership to your class and so not give the same connection to anyone else.